# I've used this xmlhttprequest approach to be able to make a real-time gauge chart that shows water quality but not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Without this xmlhttprequest, the gauge chart is working fine and showing up like here

[image]

But after I add this code in index.php, the chart suddenly stop showing up which happens when there is something wrong (even if there is no error that is being detected) but I can't find out where...

Index.php Code for automatically updating/ refreshing the gauge chart data with interval without reloading the page.

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
 ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="link_wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("link_wrapper").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "server.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
setInterval(function(){
    loadXMLDoc();
    // 1sec
},1000);

window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
</script>
```

Server.php      Code for the dynamic gauge chart

```
 <?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adminpanel');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_waterquality ORDER BY id DESC';

        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {

        ?>

            <html>

            <head>
                <div class="justify-content-between">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.charts.load('current', {
                            'packages': ['gauge']
                        });
                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                        function drawChart() {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Label', 'Value'],
                                ['Temperature', <?php echo $row['temperature'] ?>],
                                ['pH', <?php echo $row['pH'] ?>],
                                ['DO', <?php echo $row['DO'] ?>],
                                ['Turbidity ', <?php echo $row['Turbidity'] ?>]
                            ]);
                        <?php
                    }
                        ?>
                        var options = {
                            width: 500,
                            height: 200,
                            minorTicks: 5,

                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                        }
                    </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px,; margin-top:30px"></div>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Is the AJAX request sent properly? Does the server return the expected data (which I would not assume, as you start a new `<html>` block for each row from your database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this properly is to only use the PHP to get the DATA and then run it in the page.

Return JSON from your database and pass it to the function that executes the visualization.

This is your NEW server.php - it is complete

```
<?php

  header("content-type: application/json");

  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adminpanel');
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_waterquality ORDER BY id DESC';
  $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run); // assuming ONE result
  echo <<<EOT
  [
    ["Label", "Value"],
    ["Temperature", $row["temperature"]],
    ["pH", $row["pH"] ],
    ["DO", $row["DO"] ],
    ["Turbidity", $row["Turbidity"]]
  ]
  EOT
?>
```

and use this page to call it

Uncomment the commented fetch after testing

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <title>Gauge</title>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script>
    /* ------------- Remove when you uncomment the fetch -----------*/
    let temp = 25; // testdata
    const arr = [
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Temperature', temp],
      ['pH', 7.2],
      ['DO', 60],
      ['Turbidity ', 10]
    ]; // testdata
    /* ------------- END Remove -----------*/

    let chart;
    const options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 200,
      minorTicks: 5,
    };
    const drawChart = arr => {
      if (!chart) chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div')); // only do this once
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    const getData = () => {
      /* UNCOMMENT after test
       fetch('server.php')
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(arr => {
           drawChart(arr);
           setTimeout(getData, 2000); // run again
         });
       */
      /* REMOVE AFTER TEST */
      drawChart(arr); // remove after test
      arr[1][1] = ++temp
      setTimeout(getData, 5000); // run again - remove after test
      /*  END REMOVE   */

    };
    window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when page loads
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['gauge']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData); // start
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="justify-content-between">
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px,; margin-top:30px"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need to create an array of all rows, here is how to loop

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c371c0da3a5e7a91bcf8cf1e961f822c0755e57

```
$arr = array(array( "Label", "Value"));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
  array_push($arr,
    array("Temperature", $row["temperature"]),
    array("pH", $row["pH"] ),
    array("DO", $row["DO"] ),
    array("Turbidity", $row["Turbidity"])
  );
}

echo json_encode($arr)
```

Comment: Hello, I'll try it if it will work and understand the json_encode approach first. Also, I'm just currently testing it but I'll set the interval longer. Thank you.

Comment: About the first code you post, so everything will stay the same right except I will just remove the while?

Comment: The php I wrote is the complete php, the html and JS I wrote is the page that calls it

Comment: Yes they are but will that be still dynamic? Also at the php, im getting confused at the echo [ <<<eot    format like I'm not familiar on how to echo rows without a while... I can't align it to my current codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238897/discussion-between-corbin-jones-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I added how to loop your database. To make the chart you have all values (except time) and you can extract the last set of temperatures for the gauge